# How to use xsl:if test on a variable inside a different path

Tags: xslt

I've a variable = 1 in a path and i can check it by a template at that level:

```
<xsl:if test="myVariable = value">
    do this
```

I need to check that variable for another path without applying that template.
Could i just change something inside the xsl:if statement?

Could you help me please? 
Thanx

Comment: @update for other path i mean an upper node: i can read the variable from x/y/z but i need to read it from x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare a variable within a node, it's available only within that node. So to use your example, it won't be available from node "x" or "x/y", only from "x/y/z". If you want to use it at several levels, declare it at a higher node, or make it a global variable.

Comment: Solved declaring another variable at higher node. Another way I found was to implement another template reaching that level to test that variable. Thank you